# How to write parallel queries in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, es6-promise

```js
var form = require( 'express-form' );
var {validationResult, param} = require('express-validator');
const { connect } = require('http2');
const { execute } = require('node-promise');
 

module.exports = {
 
 function(req, res, groupid, programid  ) {
 

 
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if(!errors.isEmpty()){
    return res.status(400).json({errors:errors.array()});
 
   }

 

  var programid = req.params.programid;
  var format = req.query.format;
  var scrubbed_values = {programid, wid};
  var classicasync = require('async');
  

  if(typeof format !== "undefined" && format && RegExp(/^json$/i).test(format)){
    console.log("Debug json");
  }
 
  
const queryAsync = util.promisify(db.query).bind(db);
 
  classicasync.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      if (typeof programid != "undefined" && programid) {
        if(typeof programid == "string") {
          if (!programid.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
           
            localfunctions.display_error_message(res,scrubbed_values);
            return callback(null,0);
          } else {
            scrubbed_values.programid = parseInt(programid);
            callback(null,scrubbed_values);
          }
        } else {
          scrubbed_values.programid = parseInt(programid);
          callback(null,scrubbed_values);
        }
      } else {
        localfunctions.display_error_message(res,scrubbed_values);
        return callback(null,0);
      }
    },



    function(scrubbed_values,callback) {
    
 
      classicasync.parallel({
        result1: function(parallelCallback){
         
          
     
          const query1 = "";
       
          queryAsync(query1, [groupid, programid], function (err, result1) {
 
        
            
              if(err){
                  console.error(err);
                  localfunctions.display_error_message(res,scrubbed_values);
                  parallelCallback(err);
                  return ;
              }
              const firstData = [];
            
 
             const data1 = result1.map(items=> {
                  const abstruct = items.ab_text;
                  
                firstData.push([abstruct]);
                
                const UserArray = {};
               
            
                for(const items of result1){
                  const label = "End User(s)";
                  const list = items.end_users;
        if(list !== null && list !=undefined){
         if(!UserArray[label]){
          UserArray[label] = [];
         }
         EndUserArray[label].push(list);
        }
        
          
           
      
            }
             
             
      
   
 
const result4 = Object.entries(EndUserArray).map(([label,list]) => ({
  label: label,
  list:list
 
 
}));
 
  firstData.push(...result4);
 


 
                     return firstData;
 
                  
                })
             
 
         
         
          
         
            parallelCallback(null, data1);
      
 
          });
        },
 
       result2: function(parallelCallback){
          const query2 = "";
          queryAsync( query2, [projectgroupid, programid], function (err, result2) {
            if(err){
              console.error(err);
              localfunctions.display_error_message(res,scrubbed_values);
              parallelCallback(err);
              return ;
          }
          const data2 = [];
          const categoryArray = [];
     
          for(const items of result2){
            const label = items.mem_role;
            const list = items.mem_name + ', ' +items.mem_org;
 
             if(label !== null && list !== null){
          if(!categoryArray[label]){
            categoryArray[label] = [];
          }
 
        }
           
         
      
        if(!categoryArray[label].includes(list)){
          categoryArray[label].push(list)
        }
    
 
      }
       
        const result = Object.entries(categoryArray).map(([label,list]) => ({
          label,
          list
         
  
        }))
     
        data2.push(...result);
 
//console.log(data2);
          
            parallelCallback(null, data2);
         
        
           })
 
     
          },
 

         
            
          
          
             })
 
        
            },
 
           
               
             


    
      
        }, function(err, results) {
       
      if(err){
          return callback(err);
      }
   
    const result1 = results.result1;
  // console.log(result1);
 
   
   const ab_data = result1[0][0];
 
 

    const result2 = results.result2;
 
   
  var result5 = result1[0][6];
  //console.log(result5);
 

const wrapper = {
  content: [
    [ {
      type: "text-element",
      detail: {
        title: "Abstract",
        format: "text_element",
        payload:[{"items": (ab_data)}]
      }
    },
 

   ],
    [
   {type: "list-element",
    detail:
     {title: "Participants",
      format: "label_list",
      payload:[{"items": result2}],
   
 
}
  
 
    },
 
/
 
}
]
 
  
   ]
 
 

};
callback(null, wrapper);



      }
      )}
   
    ], function(err, finalresult){
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({error: 'An error occurred'})
 
      };
      db.end();
      return res.status(200).json(finalresult);
 
    
     
    })
       
  }
}
```

How to use promise here in order to improve performance. This runs slower than expected. Thank you for any input on this.

Comment: you can use await Promise.all([functionCallOne(), functionCallSecond()]);

Comment: if i use queryAsync, do i need to use await with Promise? Thank you! @BippanKumar

Comment: you can use await, if you want the result from promise otherwise don't use await if results from promise is not used anywhere in the code.